# How to replace the content to multiple files?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed, perl

I have multiple files containing content like the following:

```
File 1

NC_12548  og789 |nd784  -2 -54 -6

NC_12548  og789 |nd784  -2 -54 -6

NC_12548  og789 |nd784  -2 -54 -6

File2

NC_54456  og789 |nd784  -5 -56 -6

NC_98123  og859 |nd784  -5 -84 -5

NC_689.1  og456 |nd784  -5 -54 +8

File3

NC_54456  og789 |nd784  -5 -56 -6

NC_98123  og859 |nd784  -5 -84 -5

NC_689.1  og456 |nd784  -5 -54 +8
```

I want to keep the only first two columns (NC_12345  og855) and discard rest of it. How can I do this?

Comment: I see some good answers here, why haven't you [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/353652) any one of them yet?

Answer (score 8):

With `awk` you can just use `|` as column separator and print the first column:

```
awk -F '|' '{print $1}' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

output will be concatenaded. If it's necessary to keep output in separate files, consider using a for loop in shell around `awk`

```
# assuming they're all in the same directory,  hence `*`
for fname in ./file*.txt ; do
    # add extension to current file in "$fname" variable indicate new file
    # > does the actual redirection
    awk -F '|' '{print $1}'  "$fname" > "$fname".new
done
```

Having new output in `.new` might be desirable for backup. Otherwise, we can use [`sed -i` to perform in-file replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696224/3701431). Run it without `-i` first for test trial

```
# use file*.txt if they're all in the current directory
sed -i 's/|.*$//' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
sed -i 's/\(^.*\)|.*/\1/g' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Another option is via Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

for fname in sys.argv:
    with open(fname) as fd_read, open(fname+'.new','w') as fd_write:
        for line in fd_read:
            fd_write.write(line.split('|')[0] + '\n')
```

This script is intended to be used as `./script.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` and will write output to new files with `.new` extension

Comment: `cut -d\| -f1` may be an alternative to `awk -F\| '{print $1}'`

Comment: @jno  Yes, that's an option as well. Feel free to post that as your own answer

Answer (score 4):

For cutting out some text, I always think of `cut` first, separating by `|` as in jno's comment:

```
cut -d\| -f1 file
```

Or it looks like the format is always 8 characters, then 2 spaces, then 5 more characters, so you could just cut the first 15 characters with

```
cut -c 1-15 file
```

Or you could separate fields by spaces, but since there's two spaces between the first & second fields that means you'd cut out fields 1, 2, and 3:

```
cut -d" " -f 1-3 file
```

---

Cut doesn't have in-place file editing like `sed`, but you can output to a new file, then move over the original file, for example

```
for file in {file1,file2,file3}
do
  cut -d" " -f 1-3 "$file" > "$file.2"
  mv "$file.2" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I undestand *discard rest of it* to mean that empty lines must be skipped.

**Perl:** (add `-i` to edit the original files)

```
perl -lnE 'say $1 if /(.*) \|/' file*
```

**sed:** (add `-i` to edit the original files)

```
sed 's/ \|//;/^$/d' file*
```

**AWK:** (add `-i inplace` to edit the original files)

```
awk 'NF {print $1" "$2}' file*
```